# Selecting first child based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna be able to select a specific set of child in which an attribute is defined.

But how to select childs which are first child of the root selector that having the attribute `data-role`

`first-of-type` selector doesn't work due to the type of the element.

#### Here we have a sample of the DOM.

```
<body>
    <div data-role="ca:panel" title="foo">
        <div data-role="ca:vbox" width="100%">
            <div data-role="ca:form">
                <div data-role="ca:formitem">
                    <div data-role="ca:hbox">
                        <input data-role="ca:textinput">
                        <div data-role="ca:menu"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="ca:formitem">
                    <input data-role="ca:passwordinput">
                </div>
                <div data-role="ca:formitem">
                    <select data-role="ca:combobox">
                        <option>[...]</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span data-role="ca:label"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button data-role="ca:button"></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button data-role="ca:button"></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

</body>
```

#### My filter should select only

- `<div data-role="ca:form">`
- `<span data-role="ca:label"></span>`
- `<button data-role="ca:button"></button>`
- `<button data-role="ca:button"></button>`

It should work in any case, meanings, it shouldn't be linked to a specific structure of the dom and must use data-role as 'selector'.

I'm not a relevant jQuery developer. I tried some selector such as `$('[data-role]:first-of-type');` but it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea to select the right set of child.

*Note: Finding the first parent is not a concern.*

Comment: Since there is no correlation between those elements, wouldn't it be easier to write them 1 by 1? `$('[data-role="ca:form"], [data-role="ca:button"], [data-role="ca:label"]')`

Comment: What is the logic of selecting `<div data-role="ca:form">`? Why not `<div data-role="ca:vbox" width="100%">`, for example?

Comment: Also after editing your code it turns out that one `</div>` is missing.

Comment: dO YOU WANT FIRST OF EACH, or just first one of all possible?

Comment: Here is a testbed JSFiddle for everyone to try out their answers. The display will make it obvious what works: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2uppww9s/2/

Comment: Thanks four the answer. The point is that I can't use a specific structure for selector. It's not my code, it's a refactoring process. In the process, each node which has a data-role attribute is parsed. It can be a div, an input, a span or whatever.

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery's `.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)?

Comment: @SpYk3HH I have to select the all elements that having a data-role attribute and aren't nested behind an element that has one. A kind of first-of-type I suppose, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `nested behind `? You mean doesn't have a parent containing one of the others that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this generically using a filter, so long as you have a start node:

JSFilter: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2uppww9s/5/

```
var root = $('[data-role="ca:vbox"]');
var matches = root.find('[data-role]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parentsUntil(root, '[data-role]').length == 0;
});
alert(matches.length);
```

Comment: Awesome! That's the solution ! Thanks for you time !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :first pseudonym to select the first occurance of a element like for example:

```
var elm = $('*[data-role="ca:form"]:first');
```

this will select * any type of DOM-element, with the data-role that matches "ca:form"

Since you want to return two buttons with the same data-role, we cant use ":first" for that. You would have to get the first child of a  that matches in that case

```
var elm = $('td').children('button[data-role="ca:button"]:first');
```

This will look through the child elements of all TD-tags and find the first button with data-role matching "ca:button"

Comment: The problem described appears far more complex than this item-specific selector would handle. Care to provide a JSFiddle that meets the requirements?

Comment: Here is a test JSFiddle for you to try out your answer: jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2uppww9s/2

Comment: The OP says that his filter should only return those with ca:form ca:label and ca:button which is exactly what my code does. It matches against the specific data-role attributes which he wants returned

Comment: He only states by way of example what it should return for that specific layout. He also says "it shouldn't be linked to a specific structure of the dom". Also see his new followup comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want first of all overall specifications, then you can simply use selector on all three tag types and filter them as so:

```
$('div, span, button').filter(function(i){
    if (this.tagName == 'DIV' && $(this).data('role') == 'ca:form') return true;
    if (this.tagName == 'SPAN' && $(this).data('role') == 'ca:label') return true;
    if (this.tagName == 'BUTTON' && $(this).data('role') == 'ca:button') return true;
}).first();
```

Using `.first` grabs the first of them.

Also, filter can be used in a million ways to get what you want and sounds like it may get you to what you need. Just set what you're filtering for in an if/for/switch statement and return true on items that match.


## jsFiddle

---

However, if you wanted first of each you could do something like:

```
$('div[data-role="ca:form"]:first, span[data-role="ca:label"]:first, button[data-role="ca:button"]:first')
```

If variable driven in someway, just use string concatenation.

## jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks for your answer your solution is a good alternative but it requires a lot of work to run in my context. I have to check each html tag and the code shouldn't be as flexible as it as to be. This is the ultimate alternative in case of no solution appear.

Comment: @ollie314 yeah, i saw the solution grabbed. that was gonna be my next suggestion. Notice it still uses .filter. As I mentioned, a million ways to use .filter to get your result